# I'd like to combine two css files before compressing with YUI Compressor

Tags: css, intellij-idea, webstorm, file-watcher

I need to combine site.css and theme.css into site.min.css using YUI Compressor or any other plugin as a file watcher on webstorm.

I've already setup the YUI Compressor and I'm able to generate either site.min.css or theme.min.css but not both combined into just one file.

[Current file watcher configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2PRg.png)

Comment: So .. write yourself a shell/command script that will do that and then use it as File Watcher (it can run any program). Or use grunt/gulp or alike (you can also call their tasks via File Watcher).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to pass multiple files to file watcher, and the YUI Compressor itself doesn't seem to support files merging (https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/issues/255).

I can suggest using **Grunt** or **Gulp** for this - see [grunt-contrib-cssmin](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-cssmin), or [gulp-uglifycss](https://github.com/ubirak/gulp-uglifycss) with [gulp-concat](https://github.com/gulp-community/gulp-concat). See https://gist.github.com/atelic/8eb577e87a477a0fb411, https://riptutorial.com/gulp/example/13423/concat-and-uglify-js-and-css-files for some examples.

You can run the tasks using **Grunt**/**Gulp** consoles, or configure them as file watchers if you like them to be run on files changing